# Изменить по нажатию свойство display: none/block

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть div, изначально он скрыт

```
<div style="display: none">Какой-то текст</div>
```

Хочу добавить кнопку с помощью js, по нажатию на которую если display у блока none - ставит block, а если уже block, наоборот - скрывает.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

К стилям, прописанным непосредственно в `style` можно обратиться через свойство `style`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var div = document.querySelector('div')
  div.style.display = div.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<div style="display: none">Какой-то текст</div>
```

Но конкретно с показом и скрытием гораздо лучше воспользоваться свойством `hidden`, надо только не забыть прописать для соответствующего атрибута `!important` в стилях - это позволит переключать видимость элементов независимо от того, какой display стоял изначально:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var div = document.querySelector('div')
  div.hidden = !div.hidden
})
```

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<div hidden style="display:flex">Какой-то текст</div>
```

PS: Само собой, поиск элементов по тегу - это только для примера.

Comment: А если у меня несколько дивов, а мне нужно скрыть только один?

Comment: @СергейПлотницкий, в этом случае диву, который надо скрывать - присвойте уникальный идентификатор, например `id="la-la-la"` и обращайтесь к нему по этому идентификатору `var div = document.getElementById('la-la-la')`

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался!

Answer (score 3):

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let el = document.querySelector('div');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  el.style.display === 'none' ? el.style.display = 'block' : el.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: none">Какой-то текст</div>
<button>Show</button>
```

Comment: `el.style.display = (el.style.display === "none") ? "block" : "none";` - можно и в таком виде)

Answer (score 2):

Если необходимо создать кнопку именно через js (Таким же образом можно просто найти кнопку через аналогичный поиск элемента, если кнопка эта уже есть):

```js
window.onload = function () { // При загрузке страницы
    let main = document.getElementsByClassName('main'); // Ищем родительский блок с классом main
    let button = document.createElement('button'); // Создаём кнопку
    button.innerText = "Название кнопки"; // Добавляем текст в кнопку
    main[0].appendChild(button); // Добавляем кнопку в родителя
    button.onclick = function () { // При нажатии на кнопку
        let div = main[0].children; // Ищем всех children элемента с классом main
        if (div[0].style.display == "none") { // Если div имеет параметр display none, то показываем, в противном случае скрываем.
            div[0].style.display = "block"; // Первый div в этом блоке отображаем (Так же можно добавить ему класс и искать по классу)
        } else {
            div[0].style.display = "none"; // скрываем.
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div style="display: none">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А не случится ли бобо, если на странице окажется еще один скрипт с `window.onload` ?) И не надежнее ли `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

Что то вроде того

```js
function say() {
  alert('Навёл!');
  document.getElementById('elem').display = 'display ';
}
elem.mouseover = say;
```

```html
<input type="button" id="elem" onclick="alert('Было')" value="Нажми меня">
```

Comment: Ну и что это ??

Answer (score 0):

```js
let content = document.getElementById("content")
let show = document.getElementById("showContent")

show.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block"
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="showContent">Показать</button>
<div id="content" style="display:none;">Text</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать, если наоборот, display: block, нужно скрыть по нажатию? Как-то проверку сделать.

Comment: Можно добавить вторую кнопку, которая будет скрывать блок

Comment: let content = document.getElementById("content")
let show = document.getElementById("showContent")


show.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(content.style.display === "block"){
        content.style.display = "none"
    }
    else
    content.style.display = "block"
})

Comment: Это вариант для одной кнопки